# rewrite url when a form is submitted

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, get, form-submit

Question regarding redirection using htaccess. On a GET search form submit I get the following url:

```
http://www.example.com/search/?criteria=foo&filter=all&date=all&submit=search&page=1
```

The above works fine. Then I have this rewrite rule in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ search.php?criteria=$2&filter=$3&date=$4&submit=$1&page=$5 [L]
```

The above also works fine. It allows me to use the following structure for my search results:

```
http://www.example.com/search/foo/title/all/1/
```

Now my question is when I click submit I would like it to use the new clearner url structure however it uses the messier one with the question marks and the equal signs. Now automatically I was thinking maybe I have to do a redirect in PHP however if I can do it with htaccess I would be happier as it means cleaner code.

I also understand I can do this with JavaScript by intercepting the click and creating the seo friendly url but again if their is a way with htaccess I would prefer that.

Hope you understand what im trying to achieve and many thanks for reading,

fl3x7

p.s im pretty new to htaccess so if you can explain/ guide etc that would be great

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't, for instance, POST to `search` and have it redirect you to `search/foo/title/all/1/`?

Comment: @stslavik Thanks for your comment. That is what I initially thought about doing however then I just thought if I can be done using htaccess it would be cooler, if their is no way to do it with htaccess I will most likely do that :)

Comment: .htaccess only handles requests after the browser sends it. Since the browser strings GETs together as `?key=val[&key2=val2[...]]`, htaccess isn't even in play at the point the URL is being written to the browser. Sorry, mate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do it solely with .htaccess.

You can do it with javascript (intercept the onclick event, construct the url string using the user entered data then redirect the page to this url), but this is not really reliable considering that javascript runs on the client side.

My suggestion is to use PHP for this. The process is the same, but I'll use POST instead of GET as a method for the form. Before the page gets rendered, detect the `$_POST` data and construct the `$url` using it. Then redirect the page to that `$url`, using `header("Location: ".$url);` It will be best to use `exit();` after this, to make sure that the code below it will not get executed as the redirect is made.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without Javascript.

An HTML form using the GET method will send form values in the query string.
There is no way to tell it to put the values in the path instead.

Answer (score 0):

You probably *should* do this with Javascript, however you *can* do it in htaccess by using redirects. I think it would be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^search\.php?criteria=(.*)&date=(.*)&filter=(.*)&page=(.*)&submit=([^&])* /search/$1/$3/$2/$5/$4 [R=302, L]
```

I hope this will work because query-strings are supposed to have their values arrive in alphabetical order.

However, a word of warning: This might not work so please take it as just a suggestion for something to try.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely nothing pretty in using seo urls for search.
It is unlikely that google guys are less smart than you, but they're using STANDARD query string way for the search. Because every other way of doing search is ugly