# htaccess rewrite not changing html form post url

Tags: html, .htaccess

HTACCESS:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^results/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ results.php?q_type_=$1&query=$2&zip=$3 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

The above code works perfectly in accessing this:

```
localhost/BOARD/results.php?zip=32124&query=analyst&q_type_=Jobs
```

from this:
localhost/BOARD/result/jobs/analyst/32124

I would like to form that post to:

```
localhost/BOARD/results.php?zip=32124&query=analyst&q_type_=Jobs
```

to automatically change the url to:

```
localhost/BOARD/result/jobs/analyst/32124
```

My form method is GET

To summarize, i want when i click the submit button on my for for the form to submit to results.php but show the url as:

```
localhost/BOARD/result/jobs/analyst/32124
```

Comment: is this the best solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365999/rewrite-url-when-a-form-is-submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule right before the rule that you already have:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /results\.php\?q_type_=([^&]*)&query=([^&]*)&zip=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^ /BOARD/result/%1/%2/%3? [L,R]
```

Comment: I would like to take the time to appologize, your answer was correct i didnt realize the url parameters had to be in the same order as the htaccess that is being submit. i appreciate it jon!

Answer (score 0):

You need to mod rewrite this: localhost/BOARD/results.php?zip=32124&query=analyst&q_type_=Jobs
by reversing it.

your code:

```
RewriteRule ^/path/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /path?$1=$2
```

then you can use the url

```
localhost/BOARD/result/jobs/analyst/32124
```

in your form action.

Comment: ???? that makes absolutely no sense. jobs, analyst, and 32124 are not directories. they are the fields being submitted to the action of the form with a method of GET.

Comment: still, "localhost/BOARD/result/jobs/analyst/32124" in this form they are directories, you need to rewrite the directory to the actual page if you're going to use it just like that in the form action.

Comment: Read my last comment. They are NOT directories. they are fields from the html form. MEANING that there are limitless possibilities of the url. MEANING i can not just "set the url to localhost/BOARD/result/jobs/analyst/32124".

Comment: And if your next insist is that i use JavaScript or PHP to create the action link, See the link here 'which i posted in my comment' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365999/rewrite-url-when-a-form-is-submitted Which ultimately means you just ran this entire post into a loop because you didn't want to read the details.

Comment: hmn...  i see what you're trying to accomplish